# Laravel Select unique count with groupBy

Tags: laravel-5, select, count, unique, distinct

I am trying to get the count of unique batches in gift_code table for each campaign. The gift_code table is joined to campaign table by campaign_id.

```
Here is some sample data for campaign table.

--------------+--------------
|campaign_id  | name        |
--------------+--------------
| 1           | abc         |
--------------+--------------
| 2           | xyz         |
--------------+--------------

Below is some sample data for gift_code table.

--------------+------------------------+--------------+
|gift_code_id | campaign_id | batch    | unique_code  |
--------------+-------------+----------+---------------
| 1           | 1           |    1     | zxc23        |
--------------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| 2           | 1           |    2     | rtc26        |
--------------+-------------+----------++-------------+
| 3           | 2           |    1     | z8723        |
--------------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| 4           | 2           |    2     | h7c26        |
--------------+-------------+----------++-------------+
| 5           | 2           |    2     | rrcf6        |
--------------+-------------+----------++-------------+
| 6           | 2           |    3     | r7y28        |
--------------+-------------+----------++-------------+
| 7           | 2           |    3     | bnc26        |
--------------+-------------+----------++-------------+
```

```
 $campaign = DB::table('campaign')
                    ->select('campaign.*', DB::raw('count(gift_code.batch) as batch_count')->groupBy('gift_code.campaign_id')->groupBy('gift_code.batch'))
                    ->leftjoin('gift_code', 'campaign.campaign_id', '=', 'gift_code.campaign_id')
                    ->get();
```

My expected results are:

```
--------------+-------------------------+
|campaign_id  | name        |batch_count| 
--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1           | abc         |    2      |
--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2           | xyz         |    3      |
--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::groupBy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
$data = \DB::table('campaign as c')
       ->leftJoin('gift_code as gc','c.campaign_id','=','gc.campaign_id')
       ->select('c.*',\DB::raw('COUNT(distinct(gc.batch)) as batch_count'))
       ->groupBy('c.campaign_id')
       ->get();
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.